# Django urls, views, regex configuration for multiple parameters

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-urls

My Problem is that I'm currently unable to track particular post with these codes:

in urls.py:

```
    url(r'^class/(?P<class_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<subject_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', highschool.lessonBasedHome, name='lesson_based_home'),
```

in views.py:

```
def lessonBasedHome(request, class_name, subject_name, slug):
    qs = Content.objects.filter(class_name__name = class_name, subject_name__name = subject_name)
    qs1 = get_object_or_404(qs, slug = slug)
    context = {
               "qs1":qs1,
              }
    return render(request, 'lesson_based_home.html', context)
```

in lesson_based_home.html:

```
{% block content_area %}
{{qs1.title}}
{% endblock content_area %}
```

But I don't know where's the problem. Please help.

Comment: Well, if you don't know what problem you are having, neither do we.

Comment: I've mentioned above that I'm unable to track particular post

Comment: But what does "track particular post" mean? What do you see? What error do you get? What happens that shouldn't, or doesn't happen that should? What are you asking?

Comment: Maybe your `[\w-]+` is too restrictive? Try replacing all `[\w-]+` with `[^/]+`

Comment: @DanielRoseman , It shows me a 404 error (Page Not Found). & I want to access one post at a time with this urls: http://127.0.0.1:8000/class/Six/Bangla/try-it/  & I've every parameter existence

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew , You're absolutely right. Your trick is awesome. I've applied it & working well. Thanks Boss & also thanks to  DanielRoseman for your effort to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[\w-]+` pattern matches one or more (`+`) characters that are either letters, digits, underscores (`\w`) or hyphens (`-`). Whenever the subpart contains any other symbol, there won't be any match returned.

To make the pattern less restrictive, replace all `[\w-]+` with `[^/]+`, a pattern that matches one or more characters other than `/`.